# woocommerce Products not showing Under products page of woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Can someone please help me. Been working on wordpress with woocommerce. Been adding products and all of a sudden. None of my products are showing. Filter showing all products but i have to select the filter before i can see any products.
Please see image below
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: are you using any multi vendor plugin?

Comment: no, not using any

Comment: Try after clearing WC Transients in woocommerce > system status > tools

Comment: Deleted all WC transients, still having same issue.

Comment: Are you using any premium theme or did u make any changes in plugin files?

Comment: nope just customer css editor that is build in , never changes any files